# .htaccess Pages open even though the URL is broken

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with my website opening pages that should show 404 error. It seems that only the first part of the URL is taken into account.

Here's an example

```
example.com/page.php - (opens - correct)
example.com/asdasd.php - (error 404 - correct)
example.com/asdasd.php/asdasd - (error 404 - correct)

example.com/page.php/asdasd - (opens - incorrect)
example.com/page/ - (opens - incorrect)
example.com/page/asdasd (opens - incorrect)
```

I would like to get an Error 404 and if I feel that the URL is important  also be able to Redirect it. Now I can't even Redirect URLs that for example look like this "example.com/page.php/asdasd"

The closest answer that I found was this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|HEAD)\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

But the problem was that I got something like this:

```
Input URL
example.com/page.php/asdasd 
Output URL
example.com/page
```

I need it for the .php extention to stay. And if possible instead of "Redirecting" to the example.com/page.php, I'd like to get an Error 404

This is what I currently have in the htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I don't even know what I should look for.

Answer (score 0):

> example.com/page.php/asdasd - (opens - incorrect)

This is due to a feature called *Path Info* - if Apache manages to match the first part of the requested URL to an existing file, then it will serve that file, and pass the rest of the path along via environment variables (so that a script could in theory make use of this information.)

The `AcceptPathInfo` directive makes it possible to disable this behavior.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo